# App becomes slow when trying to encode UIImage and storing to NSUserdefault

Tags: objective-c, ios, url, encoding, uiimage

I am trying to save a list of users (with UIImage property) to NSUserdefault whenever the user clicks on a certain tab in my app.

In my 'user' object, I implemented the encoding as shown below:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.avatar_url];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    self.avatar = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] autorelease];

    [encoder encodeObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.avatar) forKey:@"avatar"];
}
```

However, I realize that by doing this, my app hangs after clicking on the tab that triggers the saving to NSUserdefault. I attribute the slow performance to the conversion (and encoding) of a UIImage from a URL.

Is there a way to speed up this process of encoding and saving an image to NSUserdefault (that does not cause the app to lag).

Comment: Couldn't you save the url instead of the image itself?

Comment: You could also try saving the image in a separate thread using GCD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it is slow is because you are blocking the main thread until the image downloads. Whenever performing operations that rely on network activity you should move that to a background thread. And as @Richard J. Rosss III pointed out you can save the data directly, there is little reason to convert to an image then back to data unless you absolutely need a png and the original format was not png.

[Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: +1. Always do web request asynchronously. It's probably not the encoding and saving that's slow.

Answer (score 1):

If the URL is remote (rather than a local `file:///` URL) then the performance issue is probably that of downloading it - look into using `NSURLRequest` and related classes to download the avatar asynchronously (in the background) and then store it to `NSUserDefaults` afterwards.

Also note that writing an image to `NSUserDefaults` is not the intended use case - you'd be better off writing it to a file in your documents directory:

```
NSString *path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"avatar"];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

And to fetch:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```